# Can a 9.3 MSD be created with ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcmap, msd

I know that we can save to a 9.3 MXD document using ArcGIS 10.

Is it possible to export to a 9.3 MSD (optimized map document) using ArcGIS 10?

Comment: you mean to use with ags 9.3?

Comment: correct, we want to create a MSD that could be loaded into ArcGIS Server 9.3.1 with ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap) 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say no.  In ArcObjects, the IMSDHelper interface (used to open and save MSD files) has a SaveAs method, but there is no version parameter,  and the MSDHelper class does not implement IDocumentVersion.